# How do I set up a login session timeout in Meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

(I'm asking questions using a translator.)

I'm not storing user information in the users collection, but in a separate collection I've created.

If the user does nothing for 10 minutes after logging in, I want to log out automatically.

The session API provided by Meteor seems to be available only to clients.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

#### How about use [stale-session](https://atmospherejs.com/zuuk/stale-session)?

Stale session and session timeout handling for meteorjs.

```
meteor add zuuk:stale-session
```

- The user will be logged off whether the browser window remains open or not.
- The user is logged off by the server and disabling javascript in the browser (kind of pointless in meteor!) would not prevent automatic log off.
- The user can be logged on multiple times on multiple devices and activity in any one of those devices will keep the sessions alive.
- The plugin uses a heartbeat that is configurable but defaulted to ensure that the server is not inundated with heartbeats from clients in systems with many concurrent users.